# How to pass a crypted message to browser with GET?

Tags: php, html, browser, phpseclib

I utilise RSA for crypting some data and I wish to pass data to my server as a GET link in this way:

```
myserver.ext/index.php?data=Âhå/2#ÛI§cw¦»L¸ÙvóìßKßàë%`N5 Ï'üQn6ÕYì&7ï,Î}:i!öççk\¶Z:Ò/MTÚFÿ*ßÕ®ØÒ¿¢y:ïM&CçëöÑ¤Û5Âÿ­QöÎÙ Ð=Páë*¹-fð
```

If I type 'enter' on this link the borwser adds special characters (to purify link I think) and If I print content of 'data' with

```
echo $_GET['data'];
```

but php cuts the content.
Is there a way to solve this issue?

Thanks.

**Edit:** I tried with encoding url but RSA decryption doesn't works. The strange thing is that in my local server (LAMPP) it perfectly works, but not on remote server.

Comment: Make sure you urlencode the data before sending it to the webserver

Comment: What output does `echo $_GET['data'];` provide? Have you encoded it?

Comment: Why not just use `POST`?

Comment: @h2ooooooo I cannot use POST because I must open a link from linux terminal and I only know how to use GET

Comment: @bit What client do you use? cURL? wget?

Comment: @h2ooooooo I simply use _chromium php mycode.php_ in a bash script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use these functions to encrypt/decrypt your data

```
    function rsa_encrypt($yourPublickey, $message)
    {
        $rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
        $rsa->loadKey($yourPublickey);
        $encrypted = urlencode(base64_encode($rsa->encrypt($message)));

        return $encrypted;
    }

    function rsa_decrypt($yourPrivatekey, $cryptedData)
    {
        $rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
        $rsa->loadKey($yourPrivatekey);
        $decrypted = $rsa->decrypt((base64_decode($cryptedData)));

        return $decrypted;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use either `urlencode` or `base64_encode`, and decode accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

For passing slashes by url without changing it into new action or folder you must convert all the "/" to some specific pattern I used "---" and in your code convert all the "---" to "/" and you get your value in the get arguments.

like:

```
var temp = replaceAll('/','---',your_link);

function replaceAll(find, replace, str) {
 return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
}
```